# Facebook Login but still not success

Tags: javascript, php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
script type="text/javascript">

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      alert("Facebook Success Connected");
      testAPI();
    } else {
      alert("Facebook Not Success Connected");
    }
  }

  function onClickLogin(){ 
 window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth/?client_id=885565114939555&redirect_uri=https://www.xxx.id/this_page.php&scope=public_profile,email,user_birthday";}

  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
  FB.init({
    appId      : '885565114939555',
    cookie     : true,  
    xfbml      : true,  
    version    : 'v2.8' 
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=885565114939555";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {"fields":"id,name,email,birthday"}, function(response) {
      window.location = "https://www.xxx.id/xxx.php" + sUrl + "&name=" + response.name + "&id=" + response.id + "&email=" + response.email + "&bd=" + response.birthday;
    });
  }
/script>


<button onclick="javascript:onClickLogin();">facebok</button>
```

1. I start by opening this_page and get popup alert "Facebook Not Success Connected".
2. I click the Facebook button and signin Facebook login.
3. After I succeed with Facebook login and redirect to this_page, but I still get popup alert Facebook Not Success Connected

This is happenening when I open in android lollipop "Sign-in to Wi-Fi network". Is there any wrong?

Comment: you are using the JS SDK already, so...why not use FB.login?

Comment: I have already using FB.login but after signin Facebook login, suddenly blank screen appeared.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(response)` and see what exact error response you are getting.

For reference, You can give this code a try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#example maybe this can give you a better idea.

Comment: where I can see console.log in webview?

Comment: If you are using Google chrome then right click on the browser window => select inspect => then select console from the available options.

Comment: In my computer it's working well. But it's only happen when my android lollipop connect hotspot, and "Sign-in to Wi-Fi network" appeared. In "Sign-in to Wi-Fi network", I cannot inspect console.

Comment: Open the page on the browser where are trying to sign in with Facebook and open the inspect window or you can press f12 if you are using windows system.

Comment: In "Sign-in to network" view I cannot inspect console. In the browser it's working well.

Comment: If in the browser it's working well it will work same on other platforms as well. But I am not able to understand your issue about In "Sign-in to network" view ?? what is this mean